# Not able to see what i enter in TextInput

Tags: react-native

I am not able to see any text I type on `TextInput`. The text is being typed but I am unable to see it.

I have tried using `state` and styling the `TextInput` but still, it doesn't work.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from './Common';

class LoginForm extends Component {

state = {text: ''}

render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <View>
                <TextInput 
                    value={this.state.text}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
                    style={{height: 20, width: 100}}
                    placeholder={"Can you see this?"}
                    placeholderTextColor={"red"} 
                />
            </View>

            <View>
                <Button>
                    Log In
                </Button>
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show me the whole code.

Comment: I have edited the whole class

Comment: I'm updated my answer. Please Check my answer and If my answer has been helpful in solving your problem, please select an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value specified is different.

```js
class LoginForm extends Component {

state = {text: ''}
...
    <View style={ alignItems: "center",justifyContent: "center",flex: 1}>
<TextInput 
                    value={state.text}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
                    placeholder={"Can you see this?"}
                    placeholderTextColor={"red"}
                    style={{height: 20, width: 100}}
                />
 </View>

}
```

OR

```js
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: ''
    };
  }
...


     <View style={ alignItems: "center",justifyContent: "center",flex: 1}>

                <TextInput 
                    value={this.state.text}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({text})}
                    style={{height: 20, width: 100}}
                />


                <Button>
                    Log In
                </Button>

        </View>

}
```

Comment: Nothing is working. Maybe there is a problem with my emulator.

Comment: @Vishesh_Malhotra Could you try change this? `onChangeText={data => this.setState({text: data})}`

Comment: @Vishesh_Malhotra  Can you try changing the style of View like the answer I updated?

Comment: It too didn't work. I think the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It's like I am able to type text but not able to see what I am typing.

Comment: @Vishesh_Malhotra  Using the answers above, make sure that you can complete and view the updated placeholders.

Comment: No placeholder is also invisible.

Comment: My problem is resolved thanks for your help. I just made a separate component and style it a bit and got the text.  ThankYou @hong develop